# access to certain method of a middleware with colon (laravel 5.8)

Tags: php, laravel, backend

I want to access a certain method of `middleware`. (especially with a colon
something like this `middleware:method`)

my **middleware**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;


class middlwareName
{
    public function ...
                 ... 

    public function method(){
        if (...)
            ...
       }

    public function ...
}
```

in **routing** i tried this:

```
Route::middlware('middlwareName', ['only' => 'method'])->veiw('url', 'path')
```

but I'm getting an **error**:

> Illegal offset type in isset or empty

is there a way that I `Route` **this way**:

```
Route::middlware('middlwareName:method')->veiw('url', 'path')
```

Comment: You can't, a middlware has a `handle()` function that is called during the request/response cycle, read here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#defining-middleware

Comment: thank you. I wanted a middleware that can restrict site data based on user role(admin, superAdmin, user). so I have to create 3 middlewares right?

Comment: no, you don't need 3 middlewares, read the docs, you can pass the role as parameter https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#middleware-parameters

Comment: thank you. you helped a lot. (should I delete this question now?)

Comment: take a look at this post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308444/ive-asked-an-xy-question-what-should-i-do-with-it